# How to convert http response json data into php object, easy to identify the IDE

Tags: php

Call the API to return json data, how to convert the data into php objects, convenient phpstorm tips?

Comment: To handle the json-enconded response you can get it as an array (`$myArray = json_decode($json, true)`) or as an object (`$myObject = json_decode($json)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this json for example:

```
$j = '{ 
"a" : 1,
"b" : "test"
}'
```

Then if you `$o = json_decode($j)` you can use $o as a standard object (e.g. `$o->{a}`)
If you `$o = json_decode($j, true)` yon can use $o as associative array (e.g. `$o["a"]`)